# Django filtering a timedelta error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: django, python-datetime, timedelta, django-filter, django-annotate

I have a model **Run** that contains **start_time** and **end_time** timestamps that signify the beginning of data measuring, and the end (we call that a "run").

```
class Run(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Recently, a customer has started to perform new types of operations, and one of those requires them to know the duration of a run (easy enough to figure out), but also filtering a table based on that duration.

The filtering is the part I don't have. So trying to filter by duration (a field we don't have on the model), I came up with the following query:

```
from django.db.models import F

test_query = Run.objects.all().annotate(duration=F('end_time') - F('start_time'))
```

By using annotate, along with F operations, I am able to add a new temporary field to my query, called "duration". The new field is of type `datetime.timedelta` as it is the result of performing arithmetic on two `datetime` objects. That part works as expected.

The problem comes down to trying to filter by that newly generated annotation, by using `__gte` and `__lte` lookups:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import F

test_query = Run.objects.all().annotate(duration=F('end_time') - F('start_time')).filter(duration__gte=timedelta(seconds=50))
```

For simplicity's sake, let's assume I only want to get `Run`s that are 50 seconds or longer, as an example.

My work so far with timedelta has been straightforward enough. `end_time - start_time = timedelta_datetime_span`

Except for the Django filter, it doesn't seem to want to take that in as a parameter, throwing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/Projects/project_foo/project_foo/comp_foo/foo/views.py", line 2790, in RunsJson
    test = Run.objects.all().annotate(duration=F('end_time') - F('start_time')).filter(duration__gte=timedelta(seconds=50))
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 892, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 910, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1290, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1318, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1207, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, reffed_expression, value)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1116, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 70, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1410, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1270, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1371, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/project_foo/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 106, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

The concatenation of `.filter()` after the `.annotate()` should work on the new `duration` field, since (afaik) a `__gte` or `__lte` lookup works off of a `datetime.timedelta` object.

What am I doing wrong with the filtering here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have something like your problem in one of my task. I hope this work for you. You should use [ExpressionWrapper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions) expression like this:

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, DurationField

Run.objects.all().annotate(duration=ExpressionWrapper(F('end_time') - F('start_time'), output_field=DurationField()))
```

With this solution you can use `duration__gte` or `duration__lte`.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thanks for your help. I didn't even know about ExpressionWrapper and that handy DurationField.